# Python equivalent for C# DataTable

Tags: c#, python, datatable

I'm evaluating Python as a technology to use for an upcoming project. Is there a construct that provides similar functionality to the C# DataTable (typed columns, integration with DB BCP functionality)?

Thanks,
R

Comment: I think you can use IronPython for this.

Comment: I was hoping to keep it cross-platform, so I don't think IP will work.

Comment: try the Pandas library which gives data frames that support hetrogenous data types.